# Unable to cast object of type 'FileStreamDeleteOnClose' to type 'System.IO.MemoryStream'.

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

Issue while generating crystal report. It was working fine when hosted on Sql Server SP 2008. Shows error on sql server 2012. 
I cant change the code right now. What can I do other than that?
I have installed Crystal Report version 13.0.2000